# How do you take a string from user and split it up?

Tags: java, string, splitter

I am trying to write a Java program that:

- Store the string in a variable called inputStr and the integer in a variable called inputInt.
- Pass inputStr and inputInt to a method called splitter. The splitter method splits the input
- string by exactly inputInt characters at a time and prints each in a line. Only the splits that
- have exactly inputInt characters should be printed.

This is the code I have so far:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("What is your Phrase? "); 
 String inputStr;
 inputStr = keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter a Integer");
 int inputInt;
 inputInt=keyboard.nextInt();

 for(int i =1;i<20;i++){

 inputStr.substring(0, inputInt);



 }
```

The program should look like this:
Please enter a string: ThisIsAnExample
Please enter an integer: 3
Thi
sIs
AnE
xam
ple

Example2:
Please enter a string: ThisIsAnotherExample
Please enter an integer: 6
ThisIs
Anothe
rExamp

Note that in example 2, the last 2 characters (“le”) are not printed since they don’t have 6
characters.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question :) Have you looked up how to take input and parse a string in Java?

Comment: I thought I did ask a question?

Comment: What is parse string?

Comment: `What is parse string?` You need to work on your Google-fu. Seriously, just Google `parse string java`. Founds LOTS of helpful results for your specific assignment including the duplicate I linked by just searching for `java split string by number of characters`

Comment: Not an answer but you can declare and initialize variables in one line, e.g. `String inputStr = keyboard.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code Like This:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your Phrase? "); 
        String inputStr;
        inputStr = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a Integer");
        int inputInt;
        inputInt=keyboard.nextInt();
        for(int i =0;i<inputStr.length();i+=inputInt){     
            if(i+inputInt < inputStr.length())
                System.out.println(inputStr.substring(i,i+inputInt));
            else
                System.out.println(inputStr.substring(i,inputStr.length()));
        }
    }
```

`for(int i =0;i<inputStr.length();i+=inputInt)` Increments the loop the number entered by the user times. `inputInt`

The print the string from that `i` position to the `i+inputInt` to break the string.

The If and else loop used to avoid the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` beacuse consider if a user want break 5 letter word in 3 letters. The final string will have 2 letters and will throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` Exception.

-----------------------------------EDIT --------------------------

To match the Example 2:

```
inputInt=keyboard.nextInt();
        for(int i =0;i<inputStr.length();i+=inputInt){     
            if(i+inputInt < inputStr.length())
                System.out.println(inputStr.substring(i,i+inputInt));

        }
```

Comment: This helped a lot, but like example 2 since le didn't have 6 chracters it isn't present how would you do that.

Comment: Check the edited part @kylwalfer

Comment: Instead of checking every iteration if candidate could be processed, i suggest you to add i <= inputStr.length()-inputInt inside loop condition;. Also before processing it, check if inputStr is not greater than inputStr.length. Consider all logic to extract to method

Comment: It needs to be inside the method splitter. how would I do that

Comment: @kylwalfer I did not undertood `It needs to be inside the method splitter` can you explain

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i += inputInt) {
    System.out.println(inputStr.substring(i, i + inputInt);
    // store the substring if you want to do something with them later
    // I am just printing them
}

if (i - inputInt < inputStr.length()) {
    // Print remainder, if there is any.
    System.out.println(inputStr.substring(i)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String.substring is definitely the way to go here. You'll want a loop, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-inputInt+1, i = i + inputInt) {
    String sub = s.substring(i, i+inputInt);
    System.out.println(sub);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop index need to incremented with `inputInt`. Try

```
    int i;
    for(i =0;i< inputStr.length()- inputInt;i+= inputInt){
        System.out.println(inputStr.substring(i, i + inputInt));
    }
    // For remaining substring
    if(i < inputStr.length()){
        System.out.println(inputStr.substring(i));
    }
```